# OCamlで .. （点が二つ）の使い方はいくつありますか

Tags: ocaml

「プログラミングin OCaml」 を見ています、
他のプロジェクトも見ていて`..`の使い方に疑問を持って質問させていただきました。

この本では`..`の使い道はオブジェクト定義の拡張でした（列の多相性）、例（251ページ）：

```
# let test_calc c = c#input 10; c#plus; c#input 20; c#eq = 30;;
val test_calc : < eq : int; input : int -> ’a; plus : ’b; .. > -> bool = <fun>
```

しかし、あるプロジェクトのコードを見たらこのようなコードがありました：

```
type 'x ccc = .. ;;
```

少し関連はあると思いますが、実際これはどういうことか分からなくて悩んでいます、教えて頂くと助かります、宜しくおねがいします。

> 試したこと：
> `type ccc = ..;;  (* 実行成功　＊） let c : ccc =    object   end;;`
> 一行目は実行成功しました（この文法は間違っていないと証明できる）、最後には実行失敗しました（`Error: This expression has type <  > but an expression was expected of type ccc`）。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

現在の OCaml には 4種類の `..` の使い方があります。(正確な情報は文法定義 https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.14/parsing/parser.mly の DOTDOT を見てください。) それぞれを解説するのは回答が長くなりますので、列挙だけしておきます:

- 列多相を表す型: `< x : int; .. >`
- 拡張可能バリアント宣言 (open variant types ともいう): `type t = ..` (@nekketsuuu さんがご指摘のもの)
- 文字の範囲パターン: `match x with 'A' .. 'Z' -> true | _ -> false` (https://ocaml.org/manual/patterns.html)
- 拡張添字記法定義: `let (.!{;..}) = e` (https://ocaml.org/manual/indexops.html)

Comment: ありがとう御座います、勉強になりました！

Answer (score 1):

これは extensible variant types の記法です。

> Extensible variant types are variant types which can be extended with new variant constructors. Extensible variant types are defined using `..`. New variant constructors are added using `+=`.

https://ocaml.org/manual/extensiblevariants.html

Comment: 答えありがとう御座います、@camlspotter さんお方が詳しいので採用しました